# Is this vector calculus version of Lagrange's identity correct?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

[Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_identity) can be written like
$$
|\mathbf{a}|^2|\mathbf{b}|^2 = |\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}|^2 + |\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}|^2
$$
Now if we replace the vector $\mathbf{a}$ with the [Nabla operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) $\nabla$ we get
$$
|\nabla|^2|\mathbf{b}|^2 = |\nabla\times \mathbf{b}|^2 + |\nabla\cdot \mathbf{b}|^2
$$ or using the [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) $\Delta$
$$
\Delta (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v})  = |\nabla\times \mathbf{v}|^2 + |\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v}|^2
$$
This looks nice, but is it true? Can one derive and prove this identity directly via vector calculus (or by any other means)?

Comment: As the answer shows, this is false.  However, there might be a way to prove a related (but different) identity using the Kronecker delta and Levi-Civita symbol.  I don't have time to do so right now, but I'll try to revisit this over the next couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example

$$
\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{2}x^2 \hat{x}
$$

In this case

$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v} = x 
$$

and

$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{v} = 0 
$$

Therefore

$$
|\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}|^2 + |\nabla \times \mathbf{v}|^2  = x^2 \tag{1}
$$

On the other hand

$$
\Delta (\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v}) = \Delta(x^4/4) = 3x^2 \tag{2}
$$

From (1) and (2):

$$
\Delta (\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v}) \ne |\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}|^2 + |\nabla \times \mathbf{v}|^2
$$